# How to store per-user temporary files?

Tags: delphi

I need to store some temporary files from my program sometimes, currently I use the AppData path which works. However, I have just been trying my program on a non Admin (guest) account on Windows. This is resulting in errors because Windows is refusing me access to the AppData folder.

What would be the most ideal path to use instead of AppData, that even a user with the lowest permissions can use?

I tried Googling this one because I am sure I have seen an article on the Microsoft website that lists the different paths and requirements needed but I can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: Is `%TEMP%` not set to something appropriate?

Comment: `AppData` is AFAIk allowed for the current (non-admins too!)... what errors do you get exactly ?

Comment: The error is from an Exception I have in my code from when I try to save the files to the AppData path. It all works fine on Admin account, just not guest.

Comment: @Craig I assume you mean `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`.

Comment: Well they are saving here: C:\Users\Craig\AppData\MyTempFiles\

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to store temporary files then use a sub-folder in the temporary directory. Use [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find out where this is.

Note that on all modern versions of Windows, this folder is a per-user folder and is not shared between different users. If you want a location that is shared between all users then you need the [`CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) folder. However, as you have discovered, standard users do not have rights to write in the folder. The standard approach is for the installation program to create a sub-folder with a permissive ACL that allows sufficient write access for standard users.

Comment: I will see if I can configure Inno Setup to create this directory for me, and let my program do the rest hopefully. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you said temporary files in the Q. Did you really mean that? If so then use `GetTempPath`. Are they meant to be per-user or per-machine? I still am a little unsure what you really want to do hence me hedging my bets in the answer.

Comment: I thought AppData was a temp folder, apologies for the confusion. Per user I think is what I need.

Comment: OK, so you need per-user. Next decision is whether or not the files are temporary. In other words, do they need to persist from one session of your program to the next?

Comment: no they are not persistent, I dump the files, read them, then delete them instantly when needed (behind the scene operations). There are not many files and they are small.

Comment: GetTempPath is what you need then